# The best way to convert a real valued number to an integer value larger than 32 bits?

Tags: system-verilog

Are there any system functions that support more than 32 bits in System Verilog? I want to convert a real-valued quantity to an integral value that contains more than 32 bits. The $rtoi() system function does precisely what I want for values that can be represented in 32 bits or less. Is there a built-in for this, or would I need to write my own?

For a concrete example, I would like to be able to do something like the following:

```
logic [41:0] test_value;

initial begin
    test_value = $rtoi($pow(2.0, 39.5));
end
```

Where, instead of $rtoi(), I would use the unknown sought after system function. Given the correct function, I would expect this to result in test_value being initialized with the bit sequence `42'b1011010100000100111100110011001111111001` or possibly `42'b1011010100000100111100110011001111111010` if rounding is supported.

I can write my own function, but I would like to avoid reinventing the wheel unless there is no wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A implicit cast from real to integral gives you what you want with rounding

```
test_value = 2.0**39.5;
```

Or you can use an explicit cast

```
typedef logic [41:0] uint42_t;

test_value = uint42_t'(2.0**39.5);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @dave_59. Those both worked for me. FYI: There is a typo in your explicit type cast, the identifier for the declaration is uint42_t and the cast has an extra underscore uint_42_t... I tried to fix it, but it doesn't let me because I didn't change at least 6 characters.